# three.js[r84] weird 1 pixel vertical line on envMap Reflection using MeshPhongMaterial

Tags: three.js

it's seems there may be a bug on the envMap implementation of MeshPhongMaterial.

I built a simple scene with a Sphere and a MeshPhongMaterial with an envMap texture (half white and half black);

You will see in the attached image, that a vertical 1px line appears in the reflection, that should not be there.

Did anyone has this problem? Is there any workaround?

[scene render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEtUc.png)
[envMap texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsfKT.png)

Here is the code I used

```
    var mat1= new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color:0x999999, 
        specular:0xFFFFFF,
        reflectivity:1,

    });

    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.load('test1.png',function ( texture ) {

       texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
       texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
       texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
       texture.repeat.set( 1 , 1 ); 

       mat1.envMap=texture;
       mat1.needsUpdate=true;
    });


    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry( 35, 32, 32 ), 
                              mat1 );      
    scene.add(mesh);
```

Thanks

Comment: what if you use `THREE.SphericalReflectionMapping`?

Comment: I tried but that's a different kind of effect. With SphericalReflectionMapping The reflection does not change as you move the camera.

Comment: only as a workaround, try changing the uv coords from being 1.0 to 0.99.

Comment: My guess is that your image is 536x283 and this is causing a mapping issue. Since envMap relies on the addition of the shader helper, I would resize your image to 512x256 or preferably  256x256 or 512x512 and so on. Gaitat's suggestion would compensate for this issue too.

Comment: I tried setting Texture.repeat (0.99,0,99) but has no effect when mapping is "EquirectangularReflectionMapping"
I also tried with 512x512 textures (any power of 2) with no luck.